# Compare objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have next object:

```
rows = [
  {
    name: "user1",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  },
  {
    name: "user2",
    previlege: "Reportering"
  },
  {
    name: "user3",
    previlege: "Filtering"
  }
]
```

And another object:

```
selected = {
  name: "user1",
  previlege: "Filtering"
}
```

I want filter rows and delete object which matched, so I need to compare them. I tried like this:

```
rows.filter(function(object) {
  return JSON.stringify(object) !== JSON.stringify(selected);
});
```

But it doesn`t work. How can I delete this matched object?

Comment: I ran your code in chrome's console and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare through `JSON.stringify()`, though? If you want to filter out the object with the same `name` property, but it has a different `previlege` property, it wouldn't work.

Comment: what did you mean doesn't work?

Comment: You could turn an object into a string and then do a string comparison but you could also just compare the name and privilege properties, which would probably be faster and potentially more reliable.

Comment: Are you taking the result in a new variable like `var ans=rows.filter`?

Comment: You are right I needed to use new variable and now all work. But intresting fact, my code works in console right, as Jeremy Jackson wrote.

Comment: that might be the fact that chrome is going to print the result of your `rows.filter` function... however if you don't store this result you won't be able to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the element from the array you can try to store the result of filter into a new array

```
newArray = rows.filter(function(object) {
  return JSON.stringify(object) !== JSON.stringify(selected);
});

rows = newArray;
```

Comment: Or simply `rows = rows.filter(...)`.

Comment: yeah that works too, just trying to be more explicit :)